# SVG анимация текста и линий

Tags: html, svg

Как можно сделать анимацию рисования линии от верха к первому тексту, затем появления текста и также с остальными линиями и текстом?

```html
<svg height="800" width="800" style="font-size:2rem">
    <path id="lineAB" d="M 400 350 l 0 -280" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <text x="150" y="370" dx="-30">Example text text text text text</text>
      <!-- Label the points -->
      <path id="lineAB" d="M 400 680 l 0 -280" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <text x="150" y="685" dx="-30">Example text text text text text</text>
    <path id="lineAB" d="M 400 990 l 0 -280" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
    <text x="150" y="985" dx="-30">Example text text text text text</text>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот `css+keyframes` версия, длины путей одинаковые поэтому получилось так мало css:

```html
<svg height="800" width="800" style="font-size:2rem">
  <path id="lineAB" d="M 400 350 l 0 -280" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <text id="text1" x="150" y="370" dx="-30">Example text text text text text</text>
  <path id="lineBC" d="M 400 680 l 0 -280" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <text id="text2" x="150" y="685" dx="-30">Example text text text text text</text>
  <path id="lineCD" d="M 400 990 l 0 -280" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <text id="text3" x="150" y="985" dx="-30">Example text text text text text</text>
  <style>
    path {
      /* на всех путях одинаковая анимация продолжительностью 3 сек */
      animation: path_animation 3s forwards;
      /* ширина штриха и пробела равны длине пути */
      stroke-dasharray: 280 280; 
      /* изначально ставим отрицательный отступ*/
      stroke-dashoffset: -280; 
    }

    text {
      /* текст с начала полностью прозрачный */
      opacity: 0; 
      /* анимация текста у всех одинаковая */
      animation: text_animation 1s forwards;
    }

    /* задержки включения анимации */
    #text1  {animation-delay: 3s}
    #lineBC {animation-delay: 4s}
    #text2  {animation-delay: 7s}
    #lineCD {animation-delay: 8s}
    #text3  {animation-delay: 11s}

    /* анимируем сдвиг пунктира */
    @keyframes path_animation {
      0%   {stroke-dashoffset: -280}
      100% {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
    }

    /* анимируем порзрачность */
    @keyframes text_animation {
      0%   {opacity: 0}
      100% {opacity: 1}
    }
  </style>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Arthur я видел его, но мне не показалось это настолько простым, чтобы вообще садится за это в рамках ответов на so. сами квадраты так нарисовать не сложно, а вот спроецировать туда интерфейс рабочий, тянет на проект за который неплохо должны заплатить

Comment: Тогда пролёт. Этот вопрос не тянет на 1.5к репы?)) Наверно в целях продвижения вопросов, этот вопрос даст слабый выхлоп, можем забыть об этом